# I need to integrate, but I don't know where to start. I'm a bit (a lot) rusty.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, education

Please help me solve the following integral.

I'm not sure where to start in fact, I haven't done math for 7 years and now I have to jump back in the integrals. I'm not sure if I have to integrate by part or by substitution. Wolfram Alpha tells me to start with the long division, but I'm not quite sure what it means. I would like to give you guys more information, but the thing is, I don't even know where to start, so it's kind of hard to give more details. Could you please at least tell me where to start? I'm looking in my manuals, and I just can't find it. Thank you very much!

$$
\int\frac{3x^3+2x+7}{x^2+3}dx
$$

Comment: Long division is the polynomial equivalent of reducing a fraction by taking out as many multiples of the denominator as possible. Note that $3x^3 + 9x$ is a multiple of $x^2 + 3$, so we can rewrite the numerator as $3x^3 + 9x - 7x + 7$. Thus, we have $$\frac{3x^3+2x+7}{x^2+3} = \frac{(3x^3+9x) + (-7x+7)}{x^2+3} = 3 + \frac{-7x+7}{x^2+3}$$

Comment: Also, incidentally, the $\mathrm{d}x$ is always at the end of the integral, so it would be better to write:
$$\int\frac{3x^3+2x+7}{x^2+3}\ \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: @Théophile The question has a $3x^2$ in the numerator and not a $3x^3$

Comment: Actually, it really is supposed to be 3x³, someone else edited my question.

Comment: May I suggest [Paul's Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you already mentioned you can start by "long division":

$$\int \frac{3x^3+2x+7}{x^2+3}dx=\int 3x-\frac{7(x-1)}{(x^2+3)} \space \space dx$$

For a good video on polynomial division see here: [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXgV9ySNusc)

Now you can separate your integral:

$$-7\int \frac{(x-1)}{(x^2+3)} \space dx+3\int x \space dx=\color{red}{-7\int \frac{x}{x^2+3} \space dx}+\color{blue}{7\int  \frac{1}{x^2+3}\space dx}+3\int x \space dx $$

I am assuming you know how to integrate the last integral. The red and blue integral can be solved by substitution.

Comment: It supposed to be $3x^3$, someone edited my question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Mart No problem. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @Mart Alright I fixed it. Hope it helps.

Comment: whoops! sorry about the confusion

Comment: @MichaelChirico No problem. Mistakes happen ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Combine these fractions:

$3x-\frac{7}{2}\frac{2x}{x^2+3}+\frac{7}{x^2+3}$

[Polynomial Division](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/polynomial_and_rational/dividing_polynomials/v/polynomial-division) is simply the reversal of this process